# Searching for an exact String in another String

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a very simple question and that is searching for a string inside of another string. Consider the example below:

```
bigStringList <- c("SO1.A", "SO12.A", "SO15.A")
strToSearch <- "SO1."
bigStringList[grepl(strToSearch, bigStringList)]
```

I'm looking for something that when I search for "SO1.", it only returns "SO1.A".

I saw many related questions on SO but most of the answers include grepl() which does not work in my case.

Thanks very much for your help in advance.

Comment: You need to escape the "." or it will be interpreted as a metacharacter and not an actual period.  Try this `strToSearch <- "SO1\\."`

Comment: @Frank, awesome. That's the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When searching for a simple string that doesn't include any metacharacters, you can set `fixed=TRUE`:

```
grep("SO1.", bigStringList, fixed=TRUE, value=TRUE)
# [1] "SO1.A"
```

Otherwise, as Frank notes, you'll need to escape the period (so that it'll be interpreted as an actual `.` rather than as a symbol meaning "any single character"):

```
grep("SO1\\.", bigStringList, value=TRUE)
# [1] "SO1.A"
```